# Действие с элементом при нажатии

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, есть таблица в html с ячейками, у каждой ячейки один и обработчик:

```
<td class="block" onclick="sch();"></td>
<td class="block" onclick="sch();"></td>
```

Необходимо при нажатии на ячейку добавить/удалить класс, желательно не называть каждую ячейку по разному а именно к текущей нажатой ячейке применить данное действие, js код:

```
function sch() {
    $(this).classList.toggle('orange'); //не работает
}
```

В консоли выводится ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста решение, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td class="block" onclick="sch(this);"></td>
<td class="block" onclick="sch(this);"></td>

function sch(elm) {
    $(elm).classList.toggle('orange');
}
```

Попробуйте так

Comment: Спасибо всем кто ответил в теме, но по моей проблеме наиболее полезным оказался данный ответ, только есть ошибочка, нужно было написать elm.classList.toggle('orange');

Answer (score 1):

[ClassList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) это не из jQuery, а из нормального javascript.
В jQuery есть метод [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```js
$('.block').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('orange');
})
```

```css
.orange{
  background: orange;
}
td{
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="block">1</td>
    <td class="block">2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

А без jQuery вам нужно и элемент получать нормальным способом, а не через $, иначе это не оригинальный DOM элемент и classList у него нету:

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('block')].forEach(element => 
    element.onclick = event => element.classList.toggle('orange'))
```

```css
.orange{
  background: orange;
}
td{
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="block">1</td>
    <td class="block">2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```